# "An error occurred. Please try later" trying to connect to Facebook (Windows Phone/C# SDK)

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone

((Using the C# Facebook SDK))

I have an app that's been working for a while now.. Since a few months ago, when people started getting Windows Phone 8 devices, some people have been getting an error when trying to connect the app to Facebook. I have not been able to get a clear repro on which devices/combo this happens for sadly, though it seems like it's more than one device and it seems to be happening on 7.5 devices as well.

The error some are getting is "An error occurred. Please try again." after putting in their name/pwd. I have added some debugging code and have the page content (minus pwd) they are seeing and it's just a blank page with the error at the top. The navigation that occurs on the hosted browsers is this (client_id replaced to protect my key, but I validated that it's correct).

First they get this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=touch&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&scope=friends_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_photos

Then they get redirected to this which gives the aforementioned error:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&display=touch&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&scope=friends_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_photos

---

Note that there's another class of users that are seeing a different behavior (those with 7.5 devices, I think).. They go to the same page as the previous ones, and then redirect to an empty page (when I look at the content, there's "error" at the title, but the page is otherwise empty.

I am unable to repro this on either of my devices or the various emulators (8.0/7.5 etc).

Does anyone have an idea on how to debug this?

Comment: offline_access has been deprecated. check sample at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample

Comment: @prabir: Thanks - in the example, I don't see anything relevant to offline_access. I am using a copy/paste of that example to do my auth actually. :) Also - does that explain why some users who migrated to a different phone (existing user, new phone) are now getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot. Somehow, the app transitioned to "Sandbox mode" and thus allowed only developers to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a different setup

login to my website via desktop browser was working, 
but login via mobile browser failed with "an error occured, please try again" 
I saw the problem on an old (2.2) android and an old ipod touch

I could fix the problem, by sending the user directly to the https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?... page, if he was on a mobile browser.

Users on desktop browsers still will be send to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?... page.